# Use regular expression in C# to select a specific occurrence from a string by limiting input

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Using C#, i am stuck while trying to extract a specific string while limiting the string to be matched. Here is my input string:

> NPS_CNTY01_10112018_Adult_Submittal.txt

I would like to extract 01 after CNTY and ingnore anything after 01.

So far i have the regex to be:

```
(?!NPS_CNTY)\d{2}
```

But the above regex gets many other digit matches from the input string. One approach i was thinking was to limit the input to 9 characters to eventually get 01. But somehow not able to achieve that. Any help is appreciated.

I would like to add that the only variable data in this input string is:

> NPS_CNTY[two digit county code excluding this bracket]_[date in MMDDYYYY format excluding the brackets]_Adult_Submittal.txt.

Also please  limit solutions to regex's.

Comment: If the string always start with `NPS_CNTY` and you have to extract 2 digits then you don't need a regular expression. Just use `Substring()` method

Comment: Similarly, if you _must_ use regular expressions, you can do a simple capture group using "NPS_CNTY(\d+)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?!NPS_CNTY)\d{2}` pattern matches a location that is not immediately followed with `NPS_CNTY` and then matches 2 digits. The lookahead always returns true since two digits cannot start a `NPS_CNTY` char sequence, it is redundant.

You may use a positive lookbehind like this to get `01`:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=NPS_CNTY)\d+"); 
var result = "";
if (m.Success) 
{
    result = m.Value;
}
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DNPS_CNTY%29%5Cd%2B&i=NPS_CNTY01_01141980_Adult_Submittal.txt)

Here, `(?<=NPS_CNTY)`, a positive lookbehind, matches a location that is immediately preceded with `NPS_CNTY` and then `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.

An equivalent solution using *capturing* mechanism is

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"NPS_CNTY(\d+)"); 
var result = "";
if (m.Success) 
{
    result = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! May i  know how this regex works up to asked output?

Comment: @ramadongre *`(?<=NPS_CNTY)`, a positive lookbehind, matches a location that is immediately preceded with NPS_CNTY and then `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.*

Comment: Just a note, if you are only interested in matching 2 numbers only, the end of these regex's should be \d{2} and not \d+

Comment: @raterus OP wanted to match digits after `NPS_CNTY` and tried limiting the number of digits because of the failure to get the required digit chunk. `+` is enough here.

Comment: Understood, thanks! But somehow the second capturing mechanism would not yield "01" but rather "NPS_CNTY01".

Comment: @ramadongre You should pay attention to the code I posted: `result = m.Groups[1].Value;` - the value you need is in Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

If the string always start with `NPS_CNTY` and you have to extract 2 digits then you don't need a regular expression. Just use `Substring()` method:

```
string text = @"NPS_CNTY01_01141980_Adult_Submittal.txt";
string digits = text.Substring(8, 2);
```

EDIT:
In case you need to match N digits after `NPS_CNTY` you can use the following code:

```
string text = @"NPS_CNTY012_01141980_Adult_Submittal.txt";

string digits = text.Replace("NPS_CNTY", string.Empty)
                    .Split("_", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The reason, i was preferring the use of regex was to use them as an input pattern for a series of configurations, so i would not want to use string functions.

Comment: @ramadongre in that case you should have added more examples to your question.

Comment: @ramadongre what would be the other cases? More than 2 digits? A string that starts with different characters? Could you please add more details to your question?